# AWS EKS node group migration stopped sending logs to Kibana

Tags: amazon-eks

I encounter a problem while using EKS with fluent bit and I will be grateful for the community help, first I'll describe the cluster.

We are running EKS cluster in a VPC that had an unmanaged node group.
The EKS cluster network configuration is marked as "public and private" and
using fluent-bit with Elasticsearch service we show logs in Kibana.

We've decided that we want to move to managed node group in that cluster and therefore migrated from the unmanaged node group to a managed node group successfully.

Since our migration we cannot see any logs in Kibana, when getting the logs manually from the fluent bit pods there are no errors.
I toggled debug level logs for fluent bit to get better look at it.
I can see that fluent-bit gathers all the log files and then I saw that we get messages:

```
[debug] [out_es] HTTP Status=403 URI=/_bulk
[debug] [retry] re-using retry for task_id=63 attemps=3
[debug] [sched] retry=0x7ff56260a8e8 63 in 321 seconds
```

Furthermore, we have managed node group in other EKS clusters but we did not migrate to them they were created with managed node group.
The created managed node group were created from the same template we have from working managed node group with the only difference is the compute power.
The template has nothing special in it except auto scale.

I compared between the node group IAM role of working node group logs and my non working node group and the Roles seems to be the same.

As far for my fluent bit configuration I have the same configuration in few EKS clusters and it works so I don't think that the root cause but if anyone thinks something else I can add it if requested.

Someone had that kind of problem? why node group migration could cause such issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned, always look at the access policy of the resource you are having issue with, maybe it does not match your node group role